# How to stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, recursion

Here I found an example of the loop(recursive function) delay and used for its own purposes. The problem is that with the successful addition of div I need to stop the cycle, but here is recursive function and so break throws an error.

I tried something like this:

```
(function myLoop(i){
    console.log($("input[name='show']").is(':visible'));
    if($("input[name='show']").is(':visible'))
        return false;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.getScript('index.php?ping=true', function(data){
            if(ping){
                $('#input').append('<input width="320" type="image" height="240" border="0" src="http://'+url+':'+port+'/?up" name="show">');
            }
        });
        if (--i) myLoop(i);
    }, 7000)
})(10);
```

But it stops only after second div is added. as I understand I need to somehow use the callback on if?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Solved the problem myself, just added if (--i) myLoop(i); to the getscript

Comment: Instead of recursion, why not use setInterval/clearInterval?

Comment: please create a demo : jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a reference to your `setTimeout` and the use `clearTimeout`.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    if (success) {
        clearTimeout(timeout); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would probably be to call the function again if it actually fails, and just set a limit or something similar :

```
var i=0, limit=10;

function getSomething() {
    if (!$("input[name='show']").length) {
        var XHR = $.getScript('index.php?ping=true');
        XHR.done(function(data){
            if(ping){
                $('#input').append('<input width="320" type="image" height="240" border="0" src="http://'+url+':'+port+'/?up" name="show">');
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            if (i<limit) setTimeout(getSomething, 7000);
            i++;
        });
    }
});    

setTimeout(getSomething, 7000);
```

Checking if the element exists should'nt really be neccessary as it probably won't exist until the function no longer fails etc. Also, where are you getting the variables ping, url and port from, as they are not defined anywhere ?

Comment: if(ping == 'true'){
 $('#input').append('<input width="320" type="image" height="240" border="0" src="http://'+url+':'+port+'/?up" id="show">');
}
else
 if (--i) myLoop(i);